# Does Janusgraph support Blob datatype?

Tags: java, cassandra, blob, janusgraph

I am using janusgraph over cassandra and elastic search. In cassadra blob datatype is supported for saving files.

My question:

Is it supported in janusgraph to handle and save files as blob and can any one give me a java example or api to do so?

Answer (score 3):

JanusGraph supports the following data types:

- Byte
- Short
- Integer
- Long
- Float
- Double
- String
- Geoshape
- Date
- Instant
- UUID

Unfortunately, BLOB is not one of them.

One thing to keep in mind, is that property storage inside of JanusGraph can be tricky.  For instance, properties on edges are stored on both vertices, which means they are stored twice.  Long story short, you should try to keep your property values as small as possible; and BLOBs work against that principle.

And FWIW, storing large files as BLOBs isn't a good idea in Cassandra, either.  The better option, is to store a link to the file and have your application look it up separately.